# Инициализация свойства класса

Tags: php

У класса есть свойство `$options` - массив параметров, у которого должны быть значения по умолчанию.

Можно ли (и правильно ли?), при описании класса инициализировать его значениями по умолчанию таким образом:

```
class F {
    public $options = [
        "param1" => 1,
        "param2" => [
            ...
        ]
    ];
}
```

Или лучше в конструкторе это делить и почему?

Comment: Кстати, зачем новый акк завел? Чем тебя старый не устраивал?

Comment: @Ипатьев походу из-за качества вопросов и непринятия ответов просто не дает новый вопрос создать.

Comment: @Ипатьев А какой был первый? Имеет смысл объединение учёток, или там всё плохо?

Comment: @Ипатьев просто тут некоторым нечем заняться, сидят и минусуют вопросы. С того аккаунта нет возможности создавать вопросы из-за качества вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Если это статический класс, то надо прямо в свойстве.
Если нет - то без разницы.